# Flutter: Firebase auth and Firestore snapshot stream

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

In my flutter app I'm using firebase for the authentication and firestore database. I am also trying to follow the BLOC pattern.

After succesfully login I need to build my UI screen using some data stored in a document:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Auth.of(context).firebase.uid(), 
      builder: (context, snap){

        if(snap.hasData) {
          print("Your uid is ${snap.data}");
          return StreamBuilder(

            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('USERS').document(snap.data).collection('PHOTOS').document(
                widget.photoID).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snap) {...}
```

Now, all is working fine.

Auth is a wrapper class for Firebase Auth extending InheritedWidget where .uid() method returns a Future with the user identifier.
Then I use a StreamBuilder to build the UI passing the uid to get a DocumentSnapshot.

So here is my question: is there a better approach to achieve this and avoid nesting StreamBuilder inside FutureBuilder?

Comment: I recommend this tutorial for the best and cleanest approach of integrating Firebase auth with Bloc/Cubit https://flutter-developer.medium.com/flutter-firebase-authentication-with-cubit-bloc-tutorial-1-of-2-3e44de433cf2

Answer (score 2):

You can make an `async` function which returns the Firestore snapshot and allows us to fetch the **uid future** without `FutureBuilder` and process the uid inside the function.

```
_getData() async{
    String uid = await Auth.of(context).firebase.uid();
    var snapshots = await Firestore.instance.collection('USERS')
        .document(snap.data)
        .collection('PHOTOS')
        .document(widget.photoID).snapshots();
    return snapshots;
}
```

We'll use this function in StreamBuilder

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _getData(), 
         builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snap) {...}
    );
}
```

This is my approach for avoiding nested `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
`firebase.uid()` is now sync instead of async since `0.18.0`. So you can use it directly in your stream.

Old answer:

[RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) is what you need, you can combine the `Future` and `Stream` before you pass them into a `StreamBuilder`.

```
  var mergedStream = Auth.of(context).firebase.uid().asStream().flatMap((uid) =>
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('USERS')
          .document(uid)
          .collection('PHOTOS')
          .document(widget.photoID)
          .snapshots());
```

Then you can used this stream in your `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamProvider above your Material App, Provide the auth User to to any of your widgets with Provider.of, then in a separate class call AuthStateChaged.  This will stream the auth User from signed in to null, to not signed in automatically.  Then you can you can the user around your App as needed.