# Flutter: PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but <x> has 1, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following in my app:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(currentUserUID).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.hasData) {
       return ListView.builder(
         //do some stuff here with the data
       } else {
         return LoadingAnimation();
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Pretty standard, but I am getting the error listed above.

I have vertified that currentUserID populates with the correct data before this stream is called.

In testing I have found that this error is perhaps likely caused by the fact that at runtime, "if (snapshot.hasData) {"  shows me that there is no data in the snapshot yet.   If I do anything at all, like minimise the app and refocus it again, all the data loads.  So it simply just needs a redraw.

Is there a way to do an "await" or something on this?   There must be a simple fix for this problem, seems to be a simple issue, but I just can't find a solution in any of the other threads about this.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can either do an await on this stream, or force it to update when it receives data (I kinda thought that was the whole point of a stream, but this examples proves that it doesn't do this).

Comment: can you add more details about, how you get value of currentUserUID?

Comment: In a previous screen I grab it out of shared preferences.   None of the firebase methods I have tried for getting the uid ever work.   So I take matters into my own hands, when you first sign up I store the uid as a shared pref.   I get this value before I even launch this screen.   When I start this screen the value I get for currentUserUID is jOID51blWsRA9g6Tsc3bIZzbXEa2 which then passes to the stream.

Comment: I'm not fluent with Flutter, but you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817507/10810527) and you will see a stream with an `await` operation that could be helpful. I have also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639620/10810527) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653727/10810527) that may be useful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error message actually refers to this code, that means `currentUserUID` is probably an empty string.  This is a very common mistake - if you do a Google search for the error message, you will see many others making the same mistake.

Print the value of `currentUserUID` just before you use it in order to verify that it contains the value that you expect.